# How to create a TabControl Panel with Left Aligned Tabs?

Tags: .net, powershell, user-interface

Trying to make a GUI for a powershell script I wrote and need to somehow create a tab panel with left bound tabs. I have seen tons of stuff on how to do this through Visual Studio or Powershell Studio but nothing with basic Powershell. Any advice is super apriciated!

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 2):

Set the [TabStripPlacement property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.tabstripplacement(v=vs.110).aspx) to a value of [`Dock.Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dock(v=vs.110).aspx), either programmatically on the control:

```
$tabControl.TabStripPlacement = [System.Windows.Controls.Dock]::Left
```

or in the markup:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
```

Comment: When I try the first suggestion you made it errors out. It says that the property "TabStripPlacement" cannot be found on this object. Do I have to use one of the "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Controls" or something?

Comment: Update: I got the tabs to appear on the left side but they now are now completely horizontal so you have to tilt your head to read them. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Oh, it looks like you're using Windows Forms, I automatically assumed you were using WPF/XAML

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if you're using Winforms or WPF will change how you would implement a solution to make the tabs look like the above example. With Powershell you can translate C# code over to Powershell format with a little bit of work. Here is a tutorial from MSDN written in C# that can work as a good starting point for you.

[How to: Display Side-Aligned Tabs with TabControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-display-side-aligned-tabs-with-tabcontrol)

Comment: I don't know which I am using.That said, I think I am using Winforms since I literally am just coding in powershell ISE. Also I imported "System.Windows.Forms" which I assume means I am using Winforms.

Comment: Yeah, that would be Winforms. The link above references Winforms.

Comment: Update: I got the tabs to appear on the left side but they now are now completely vertical so you have to tilt your head to read them. Any suggestions on how to fix this? I looked at your link and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: That is the difficult part. Since the TabControl isn't really designed for horizontally aligned tabs you have to define a handler for the DrawItem event of the TabControl that renders the text from left to right.

Answer (score -1):

I am using similar issue, got solution from https://www.sapien.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11354 , hope this will be helpful those who are searching with ps1 in windows form

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).